# Replacing first occurance of each word in list with a link

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I've found a very nice little script on SO that does ALMOST what I'm looking for. It replaces each occurance of a list of words with a link to wikipedia. The problem is I want only the FIRST occurance to be linked .

Here is the script (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444893/1045235)):

```
function replaceInElement(element, find, replace) {
    // iterate over child nodes in reverse, as replacement may increase
    // length of child node list.
    for (var i= element.childNodes.length; i-->0;) {
        var child= element.childNodes[i];
        if (child.nodeType==1) { // ELEMENT_NODE
            var tag= child.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (tag!='style' && tag!='script') // special case, don't touch CDATA elements
                replaceInElement(child, find, replace);
        } else if (child.nodeType==3) { // TEXT_NODE
            replaceInText(child, find, replace);
        }
    }
}
function replaceInText(text, find, replace) {
    var match;
    var matches= [];
    while (match= find.exec(text.data))
        matches.push(match);
    for (var i= matches.length; i-->0;) {
        match= matches[i];
        text.splitText(match.index);
        text.nextSibling.splitText(match[0].length);
        text.parentNode.replaceChild(replace(match), text.nextSibling);
    }
}

// keywords to match. This *must* be a 'g'lobal regexp or it'll fail bad
var find= /\b(keyword|whatever)\b/gi;

// replace matched strings with wiki links
replaceInElement(document.body, find, function(match) {
    var link= document.createElement('a');
    link.href= 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+match[0];
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match[0]));
    return link;
});
```

I've been trying to modify it (without success) to use indexOf insted of regex (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144027/1045235)), I presume this would be faster than regex:

```
var words = ["keyword","whatever"];
var text = "Whatever, keywords are like so, whatever... Unrelated, I now know " +
           "what it's like to be a tweenage girl. Go Edward.";
var matches = []; // An empty array to store results in.

//Text converted to lower case to allow case insensitive searchable.
var lowerCaseText = text.toLowerCase();
for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) { //Loop through the `words` array
    //indexOf returns -1 if no match is found
    if (lowerCaseText.indexOf(words[i]) != -1) 
        matches.push(words[i]);    //Add to the `matches` array
}
```

So my question is how do I combine these two to get the most efficient/fastest results without using a library?

Answer (score 1):

here is your code modified to do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/bW7LW/2/

```
function replaceInit(element, find, replace) {

    var found = {},
        replaceInElement = function(element, find, replace, init) {

            var child, tag, 
                len = element.childNodes.length, 
                i = 0,
                replaceInText = function(text, find, replace) {

                    var len = find.length,
                        index, i = 0;

                    for (; i < len; i++) {

                        index = text.data.indexOf(find[i]);

                        if (index !== -1 && found && !found[find[i]]) {

                            found[find[i]] = true;
                            text.splitText(index);
                            text.nextSibling.splitText(find[i]);
                            text.parentNode.replaceChild(replace(find[i]), text.nextSibling);
                            return;
                        };
                    };
                };

            // iterate over child nodes in reverse, as replacement may increase length of child node list.
            for (; i < len; i++) {

                child = element.childNodes[i];

                if (child.nodeType == 1) { // ELEMENT_NODE
                    tag = child.nodeName.toLowerCase();

                    if (tag != 'style' && tag != 'script') {
                        replaceInElement(child, find, replace);
                    }

                } else if (child.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
                    replaceInText(child, find, replace);
                }
            }
        };
    replaceInElement(element, find, replace);
};

// keywords to match. This *must* be a 'g'lobal regexp or it'll fail bad
var find = 'Lorem Ipsum bla'.split(' ');

$(function() {

    // replace matched strings with wiki links
    replaceInit(document.body, find, function(str) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + str;
        link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
        return link;
    });
});​
```

Comment: I'm seeing all 'Lorem' being linked instead of just the first

Comment: One per element, that how the code work but it replace only the first copy. It can be modified for it tho, just need to track which expressions are found.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bW7LW/2/ here this one does the job, I had to also reverse the looping of the element as otherwise it would do it from bottom to top instead of top to bottom.